# How to open a specific Chrome profile using Webdriver.io?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm using [webdriver.io](http://webdriver.io/guide/getstarted/install.html#Setup-Chrome) to open a browser instance using a node script. The browser opens but it's ignoring some of the options defined in the `desiredCapabilities` object. This is the configuration that I have right now:

```js
const path = require('path');
const webdriver = require('webdriverio');

const INIT_URL = 'http://www.google.ca';

const options = {
  desiredCapabilities: {
    browserName: 'chrome',
    applicationCacheEnabled: false,
    chromeOptions: {
      args: [
        'disable-web-security',
        'allow-running-insecure-content',
        'auto-open-devtools-for-tabs',
        'user-data-dir=/Users/david/Library/Application\ Support/Google/Chrome/Profile\ 2'
      ]
    }
  }
};

const browser = webdriver
  .remote(options)
  .init()
  .url(INIT_URL);
```

All the options seems to be working except `user-data-dir`. The browser instance opens but is not using the provided profile.

**Is there a way to configure Selenium with Webdriver.io (NodeJS) to select a specific browser profile that actually works?**

### Update

By @FlorentB. recommendation I've tried double quotes and double backslash with no success like this:

- `'user-data-dir="/Users/david/Library/Application\ Support/Google/Chrome/Profile\ 2"'`
- `'user-data-dir=/Users/david/Library/Application\\ Support/Google/Chrome/Profile\\ 2'`

But I also notice that when I see the available profiles of the Chrome instance open by Selenium the list is empty:

[image: Empty profile list]

But when I open a normal instance of Chrome (manually, without Selenium) I do see my both available profiles:

[image: Normal profile list]

Comment: The path from your example is not valid/correct.

Comment: @FlorentB. what do you think is wrong about the path?

Comment: you need two backslashes (`\\ `) to escape the space character. Have you tried to double quote the path without escaping the spaces?

Comment: @FlorentB. I did try that with no luck, please take a look at the updated part of the question. Do you know why I can't even see the list of profiles available?

Answer (score 4):

I found the solution to my own question with help of people from my company. I had to combine the property `user-data-dir` with `profile-directory` like this:

```js
const options = {
  desiredCapabilities: {
    browserName: 'chrome',
    applicationCacheEnabled: false,
    chromeOptions: {
      args: [
        'disable-web-security',
        'allow-running-insecure-content',
        'user-data-dir=/Users/david/Library/Application\ Support/Google/Chrome',
        'profile-directory=Profile\ 2',
      ]
    }
  },
};
```